# How to add column checking if values from another dataframe of corresponding attributes are contained in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`df1` looks like this:

```
  attribute_1 attribute_2
0           A           Y
1           A           Z
2           B           Y
3           B           Z

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'attribute_1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'attribute_2': ['Y', 'Z', 'Y', 'Z']})
```

and `df2` is bigger, has multiple lines of same attribute values, also with many columns different to `df1`:

```
  attribute_1 attribute_2   fruit
0           A           Y   apple
1           A           Y  banana
2           A           Z   melon
3           B           Z  orange
4           B           Z   grape
5           B           Y    pear
6           B           Z  orange

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'attribute_1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'attribute_2': ['Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Y', 'Z'],
                'fruit': ['apple', 'banana', 'melon', 'orange', 'grape', 'pear', 'orange']})
```

And I'd like to add a column to `df1` to check whether any values in `df2.fruit` of corresponding attributes are in `['apple', 'orange']`, to create `desired_df`:

```
  attribute_1 attribute_2  has_apple_or_orange
0           A           Y                 True
1           A           Z                False
2           B           Y                False
3           B           Z                 True

desired_df = pd.DataFrame({'attribute_1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'attribute_2': ['Y', 'Z', 'Y', 'Z'],
                          'has_apple_or_orange': [True, False, False, True]})
```

How can I do this? With [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) somehow?

Unsure how to describe this so please forgive me if this is already answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

First compare values by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to new column with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), then aggregate by [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) and add new column to second `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
f = ['apple', 'orange']
s = (df2.assign(has_apple_or_orange = df2['fruit'].isin(f))
        .groupby(['attribute_1','attribute_2'])['has_apple_or_orange']
        .any())
print (s)

attribute_1  attribute_2
A            Y               True
             Z              False
B            Y              False
             Z               True
Name: has_apple_or_orange, dtype: bool

df = df1.join(s, on=['attribute_1','attribute_2'])
print (df)
  attribute_1 attribute_2  has_apple_or_orange
0           A           Y                 True
1           A           Z                False
2           B           Y                False
3           B           Z                 True
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```
index = ["attribute_1","attribute_2"]

(df1.set_index(index).join(df2.set_index(index))
 .fruit.isin(["apple","orange"])
 .reset_index()
 .drop_duplicates(index)
)

attribute_1 attribute_2 fruit
0   A              Y    True
2   A              Z    False
3   B              Y    False
4   B              Z    True
```

@jezrael's solution seems more robust though, since it takes into account the groupings